# Reading from SoftLayer Message Queue

Tags: python-2.7, message-queue

I'm using the Message Queue service from SoftLayer. I have created a queue that has a few messages in it and I'm trying to read them from a Python script.

I have installed the following Python package https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-message-queue-python. Here is how my test file looks like:

```
from softlayer_messaging.queue import Queue, Message
from softlayer_messaging.compat import json
from softlayer_messaging.auth import QueueAuth
from softlayer_messaging.errors import Unauthenticated

if __name__ == '__main__':

    endpoint = "{I'm using the public host from my Message Queue credentials}"
    username = "{My username}"
    api_key = "{My API account key}"
    auth_token = None

    auth = QueueAuth(
            endpoint, username, api_key,
            auth_token=auth_token)

    auth.auth()

    queue = Queue(endpoint, "domains", auth)
    print queue.detail()
```

If I display the auth_token after calling the **auth.auth()** method, then it shows a random string, so I believe the authentication is done corectly.

The problem is that the **queue.detail()** method throws the following exception:

```
File "test1.py", line 23, in <module>
    print queue.detail()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/softlayer_messaging/queue.py", line 24, in detail
    return self.get().json
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/softlayer_messaging/resource.py", line 23, in get
    return self.request('GET', *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/softlayer_messaging/queue.py", line 20, in request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/softlayer_messaging/resource.py", line 84, in raise_for_status
    raise ResponseError("%s: %s" % (code, message), errors)
softlayer_messaging.errors.ResponseError: 404: Not found
```

I was able to connect to the queue and read the messages from a PHP script, so I'm pretty sure the problem is not with the queue itself. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

You help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, here is my code:

```
import softlayer_messaging

if __name__ == '__main__':

    client = softlayer_messaging.get_client('{queue_account_id}', endpoint='https://dal05.mq.softlayer.net/')
    client.authenticate('{username}', '{api_key}')

    messages = client.queue('{queue_name}').pop(10)

    if 'item_count' in messages and 'items' in messages and messages['item_count'] > 0:
        for message in messages['items']:

            print message['body']
```

For other endpoints, more examples can be found in the [API reference guide](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/Message-Queue).